# Capture filenames outputted from a Spark write operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can you define a `customCsvWriter` function that captures the files that are outputted when a write action is performed.  This question uses PySpark, but feel free to post Scala answers as well.

Here's the default PySpark behavior:

```py
df = spark.read.option('header', True).csv('tests/data/csvs')
output = df.write.parquet('tmp/out')
print(output) # => None
```

Here's what I'd like:

```py
df = spark.read.option('header', True).customCsvWriter('tests/data/csvs')
output = df.write.parquet('tmp/out')
print(output) # => ['part-00000-1efe6b94-810f-4aaa-ad53-bd58f05f4b9a-c000.snappy.parquet', 'part-00001-1efe6b94-810f-4aaa-ad53-bd58f05f4b9a-c000.snappy.parquet', 'part-00002-1efe6b94-810f-4aaa-ad53-bd58f05f4b9a-c000.snappy.parquet']
```

I can get the files written to S3 via a S3 event notification / SQS, but would rather have a multi-platform solution.  Delta Lake outputs the file name to the transaction log, [as described here](https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/introduction-time-travel/), so this must be possible.

Comment: why not simply list files in the output directory?

Comment: @AlexOtt - the output might have millions of files and a file listing could be a really expensive operation.  There might also be files that already exist in the directory, so you'd need to maintain a set of checkpoints like they do with Structured Streaming + Trigger.Once.  Possible, but an approach I'd like to avoid.